# Getting error using jquery: [ts] Identifier expected for $('.carousel').each(function(){}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am making an Angular project for Multi-Item Carousel Advance- 1 item per time, and using JQuery for the same. Considering JQuery is installed properly, I am getting the mentioned compilation error for $('.carousel.carousel-multi-item.v-2 .carousel-item').each(function(){}

I have tried to research a lot on Stack Overflow, but none of the answers match my question. I am very new to Angular 4 and JQuery and still trying to understand. The example that I have been referring to just defines the html and js and that's exactly how I am using it.
Below is my **team-carousel.component.ts** file. The html file for this is pretty straight forward, but https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/#multi-item-carousel-v2 is for reference.

**Updated:**

```
export class ResearchLayoutComponent{
  constructor() {
  $('.carousel.carousel-multi-item.v-2 .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
 });
}
}
```

I am not sure if I am missing anything or not, since $ shows the error as [ts] identifier expected and I am not able to figure out how to fix it. Maybe a function call is needed? Without the jquery working, the carousel is showing only one image at a time, instead of multiple images. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you add jQuery through angular.json

Comment: @AlokeT Yes, I did. Both jquery and bootstrap are added in the angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this changes.

> angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
```

> angular.json

```
 "scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
```

Now where you need to use jQuery add the following snippet of code.

```
import * from 'jquery';

(or)

declare var $: any;
```

This will solve the issue.

For more on this topic you can find here.
https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176

Comment: I already have these changes in place. I think the problem is in the **team-carousel.component.ts** file. The block of code stating the jquery (starting with $), needs to be put in a function, it cannot directly exist in the class. However, should it be put inside a constructor or a separate function altogether? If the latter, where does this function need to be called? Please let me know.

Comment: Yes you need to add them to a function as you using each function to it.

Comment: Need a little more help. As you may see, I have modified my code, and put the jquery in a constructor. But still, the carousel displays only one picture at a time. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery MDB carousel, whether it's provided angular version. see here https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/carousel/

Comment: because in the Angular version, the items in each slide, slide altogether. Whereas, I wanted the slide to happen for 1 item at a time.